# Issue saving GeoLocation using Geofire in Firebase using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm using Geofire framework for Firebase backend and I have an issue in saving locations in database.

What I need is to save the users chosen location in the `Orders` table in order of the auto generated id values.

```
    @IBAction func proceedOrder(_ sender: UIButton){

    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        if user != nil {

            let userUID = (user?.uid)!
            let scheduled = self.pickDateTextField.text!
            let time = self.pickTimeTextField.text!
            let service = self.pickServiceTextField.text!
            let model = self.carModelTextField.text!
            self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://***-****-***.firebaseio.com/")
            let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: self.ref)
            let dateCreated = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
            let orderRef = self.ref.child("Orders").childByAutoId()

            let values = ["uid":userUID,"date_Created":dateCreated,"date_Scheduled":scheduled,"time_Scheduled":time,"service_Type":service,"car_Model":model,"status":"Scheduled"] as [String : Any]
            orderRef.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, dbRef) in
                if err != nil {
                    print("Error: \(err)")
                    return
                } else {
                    geoFire?.setLocation(self.currentLocation, forKey: "Orders\(dbRef.key)")
                }
            })

        }
    })
}
```

[image: firebase console]

Answer (score 1):

Geofire is designed to keep the Geolocation data separate from your other object data. The API does not allow mixing them.

To match up the location info of an item to the other info of that item, you store them both under the same key

```
Orders
  <orderId>
OrderLocations (or whatever key you prefer, as long as it is separate)
  <orderId>
```

Comment: Thanks Frank for the fast reply. But how can i link them later together when i query an order?

Comment: Ahh ok...with the g: "id" maybe. I use the g: "id" in the orders--->id--> values

Comment: You're using the same key in both places. So `Orders/<key>` and `Geodata/<key>` correspond to each other.